# How to make whether or not VS2010 is currently debugging or not more visible

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I'm looking to be able to either toggle an option, or install a plugin that'll make it more obvious to me whether or not VS2010 is currently debugging an application or not. I'm working on a MVC4 site, and as I switch between the localhost page, the docs and VS, I lose track of whether or not VS is actually running anything, so I just always mash `SHIFT+F5` before I start editing my code, just to be sure that's it's done running.

It says '(Running)' in the titlebar, but that's not as visible as say, a colored circle in the bottom of the screen, ReSharper style.

As it stands, I've just got the Immediate Window set up to vertically split my screen, so that I can easily tell. Would love a better solution though.

Comment: Try paying attention, it's easier than finding a plugin.

Comment: @DanAndrews Thanks for that. I do see where you're coming from though, it does seem awfully lazy. Still though, I don't think it's an unrealistic request.

Answer (score 0):

i think your current solution is ok. I generally just look at the Debugging toolbar (the only toolbar I have visible, probably for this purpose) which

a) tells me I debugging (its not visible when not debugging) and
b) it has the Play option greyed out

[image]